# Why do I get different configure commands for PHP?

Tags: php

If I use `phpinfo()` and then use `php -i` from the command line, I get different configure commands. Why would they be different?

Comment: Are you doing the phpinfo from a webpage? PHP usually has two .ini files for commandline and web-based usage, and they have quite different configurations in some sections.

Comment: @Marc B: If that was an answer, I'd vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `./configure` is set to whatever was used when that PHP binary was built. While often the CLI (php -i) and the webserver module are built at the same time and thus have the same `./configure` line, that doesn't have to be the case.

But of course `php -r 'phpinfo();'` and `php -i` will give the same results. (Or at least should...)

If you are using a pre-built package, then it's most likely that the configure options won't even work as-is, as the person who built PHP would have been using a different computer. (And your computer may not have all the required dependencies.)

Also, PHP uses different INI files, and that would affect the output of `phpinfo()` and `php -i` (although different INI files wouldn't change the ./configure line).